# Assets pipeline doesn't work in 'application.scss' in my Rails 4.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I'm new in Rails and apologize if that is a stupid question. But i cannot resolve my problem: I added Bootstrap to my new app but it still doesn't use any new styles.

I've renamed application.css to application.scss and created such structure:

```
|-stylesheets
   |-elements
   |--articles
   |---article.scss
   |-application.scss
```

**Application.scss**

```
/* User styles
* Plugins first
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

@import "elements/**/*";

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 */
```

**In Gem file i've added**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2'

# Установка Bootstrap
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
#Autoprefixer optional, but recommended. It automatically adds the proper vendor prefixes to your CSS code when it is compiled.
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

I've  tried to write any style rules in article.scss but my app doesn't use them, so as any Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Try renaming the file: application.css.scss

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But it doesn't help

Comment: Try to specify relative path to article.scss instead of `@import "elements/**/*";`. Is it works?

Comment: Already done. Didnt work. Also it doens't explain why Bootastrap styles aren't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours i've found a problem - my pages_controller was incorrect:

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

instead of:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index_page
  end
end
```

Controllers should inherit from main Controller!

P.S:
Adding string `layout "application"` to the wrong controller also helped:

```
class PagesController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  layout "application"
end
```

But I do not recommend go that way

Answer (score 2):

there is an easier way, I will describe the sequence:
after adding `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` doing `bundle install`, restart server
than  add in `config/application.rb` next string:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

for your images, than create `custom.css.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets` and add there `@import "bootstrap";`,
in your `custom.css.scss` you can write your own styles

Comment: For some reason adding custom.css.scss file didnt help. 
I've already use this way in my earlier apps, where i use css instead of css.scss and it worked. But in this app - it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have an older version of bootstrap in your environment. Try updating your Gemfile with gem `'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.3'` and running `bundle`. Make sure to restart your server after the update.

Alternatively, you can just run `bundle update`.

Comment: After `bundle update` some gems were apdated:
`Installing sass 3.4.13 (was 3.2.19)
Installing jquery-rails 4.0.3 (was 3.1.2)
Installing sass-rails 5.0.1 (was 4.0.5)`
But my app still doesn't use neither Bootstrap nor my own styles