# Rails 4.1, Bootstrap 3.3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass, rubygems

I installed Bootstrap to my new project, bundler says all gems installed correctly after bundle install, but my test h1 on my root page is not rendering in Bootstrap style. Any advice would be appreciated.

In my Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'

# Use bootstrap for page stylings
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

gem 'sprockets'
```

My application.css.scss:

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

...and lastly, application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783426/assets-pipeline-doesnt-work-in-application-scss-in-my-rails-4-2-app/28783822#28783822  there are answers to your question

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `require` lines in `application.css.scss` file.

> Do not use *= require in Sass or your other stylesheets will not be able to access the Bootstrap mixins or variables.

Can you please check that?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question or just an oversized comment?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my Bootstrap issues by removing 'coffee-rails' gem and adding 'coffee-script-rails', '1.8.0'; then changing my stylesheet_link_tag in application.html.erb to 'application' from 'default'.