# Ruby on Rails - Bootstrap-rails-slider - Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I've got an issue with [bootstrap-slider-rails](https://github.com/stationkeeping/bootstrap-slider-rails)

I installed the gem as instructed on the github wiki. With the added lines as follows:

application.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "jquery-ui";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "select2";
@import "select2-bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-slider";
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require select2
```

I get the following error in my console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

When i click on sources to open the contents of the .js file for bootstrap-slider it says:

`Not Found`

I'm not sure why it can't find the file or its contents as the installation seems basic.

This might be an easy-fix issue, i thought i'd get some fresh eyes on it before i spend many more hours staring at this..

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try require `bootstrap-slider` and `select2` in `application.js` above string `//= require_tree .`

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-slider
//= require select2
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783426/assets-pipeline-doesnt-work-in-application-scss-in-my-rails-4-2-app/28783822#28783822